# 変数を別のクラスに引き渡す

Tags: c#

とあるゲームを作っています。

・expが100貯まるとレベルアップ
・レベルアップすると、ステータスクラスというクラスの変数値が１増えるようにする

ところどころ意味不明な箇所があるかもしれません。

問題は　subclassの値(exp10)をmainclassに引き渡して mainclass内でexpが100になると
レベルアップし、別のclass(例　sampleclass)に数値の1を引き渡したいのですが。またその他間違ってる箇所を指摘していただければと思います

例　敵を倒す、expを取得する(10exp)

```
class main{
public int expamount
public int exp
public void exp(){

main exp = new main();

exp.expamount

if(exp>0); boolean (exp==100) true;　//expが100と等しい場合は　レベルアップ

return;



class sub{

enemy.cs void Main(){
public int get;


monster
if(monsterHP<0); get.exp(10); //モンスターのＨＰが０になると経験値の10expゲットする。


｝
```

Comment: 申し訳ないですが貼られているコードでは全く意味が分かりません。

Comment: 現在貼られているコードは、C#のコードとしては不完全で、質問の意図をくみ取ることができません。質問者さんの手元では本題である「100expでレベルアップ」以外動いているのでしょうか。

Comment: あなたの質問では何がわからないのかわかりません。頭の中を整理してから質問したらどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

回答欄を借りて質問文のコードの問題点を指摘させていただきます。

質問としては`main()`に`public void main(int exp)`と引数を追加する方法を聞いているってことでしょうか？

```
class main
{
    public int expamount; // セミコロン追加
    public int exp; // セミコロン追加

    public void exp() // 下では「10」を渡しているのでフィールドのどちらかは引数ですか？
    {

        main exp = new main();

        exp.expamount; // セミコロン追加

        // 経験値 = 直前の経験値 + 獲得経験値; とかそういう意図ですか？
        // expとexpamountの

        if(exp>0); boolean (exp==100) true;　//expが100と等しい場合は　レベルアップ
        /* ↑のステートメントはC#としては意味が通っていません

        if (経験値 > 0 && 経験値 == 100)
        {
            // true レベルアップ処理
        }

        こういう意図ですか？
        (== 100より不等号の方が良い気がしますが)

        */

        return;

    } // 閉じかっこ追加
}  // 閉じかっこ追加

class sub
{

    /* enemy.cs ←ファイル名ですか？ */
    void Main()
    {
        /* public ←は付けられません */
        int get;
        // ↑getはexpを呼んでいるからmain型？

        monster; // ←何らかの変数ですか？
        if (monsterHP < /* <=でなくて良いのですか？ */ 0) // ; ここのセミコロンはおそらく不要です
            get.exp(10); //モンスターのＨＰが０になると経験値の10expゲットする。

    }
} // 閉じかっこ追加
```